# OpenCV Haar Cascade Validation Set Problem

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, haar-classifier, cascading

I created my own Haar Cascade Classifier using OpenCV. It works well, but I simply do not understand one element. I used opencv_traincascade application to create cascade. In https://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/boosting-ensemble/16981346.pdf when cascading algorithm is described there is an information about evaluating stage of cascade on validation set

[image]

As far as I know OpenCV implementation is based mostly on this article. I was wondering how this validation set is created. When using OpenCV tools you suppose only to set positive images and negative. I do not find any information about validation set in OpenCV documentation. Using dedicated tools do not leave space for user to declarate validation set on his own. I assumed that from declareted training set some part is taken as validation, but I cannot find information that will confirm it. So how exactly it works? Is there a scheme, which explaining how opencv creating cascade?

Comment: during training you can see the stage results and if the quality already reached the quality of the chosen max stage number it will early quit.

Comment: during training for each stage you'll see a table with HR (hit rate) which is part of the evaluation process of that stage. And you'll see FA (false alarm). In addition you'll see NEG count acceptance ration, which indirectly tells you how good your overall classifier already is (or how good/bad your negative samples are).

Comment: @Micka I agree, but to evaluate classifier you need validation set right? It cannot be evaluated on the same data (I belive), so to find if stage satisfy HR (hit rate) so in other words to evaluate your detection rate (as far as I know HR = minumum detection rate for stage) you need validation set. In opencv documentation https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html in cascade training part I cannot find how exactly evaluation is performed. I don't uderstand which part of given training set is used for validation.

Comment: @Filip I don't know the details, sorry, but I guess openCV is using the current training "batch" for finding the weak classifiers AND calculating the hit rate and false alarm rate.  While the acceptance ratio is calculated on UNUSED negative samples. There is no kind of overfitting by repeatedly seeing the same (positive) samples (while new negative samples are seen in every stage anyways), so it isn't as important as in other machine learning techniques, that there is a hard split.

Comment: @Micka I guess you answered my question, thank you!